# How do I get a different (random) independent edge set each time I run FindIndependentEdgeSet?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'd like to use FindIndependentEdgeSet[g] repeatedly to get random maximal matchings of a fixed graph, but each time I call this function it gives me the same answer (i.e. the same list of edges).

How do I "randomise" it?

Comment: @Öskå `Select[Subsets[EdgeList[g = CycleGraph[4]]], 
 IndependentEdgeSetQ[g, #] && Length@# == 2 &]`

Comment: @belisarius R-r-r-ight :) Deleting comments so I don't look stupid :P

Answer (score 3):

Example graph:

```
g = PetersenGraph[5, 5];
```

Get independent edge sets:

```
indies = Select[Subsets[EdgeList[g]], IndependentEdgeSetQ[g, #] &];
```

Get some random set (repeat as needed):

```
RandomChoice[indies]
```

(* {1<->1, 2<->2, 3<->3, 4<->9, 6<->7} *)

Edit: Rahul notes I missed the "maximal" part.

```
(* pull out only longest sets *)
With[{ml = Max[Length /@ indies]}, indiesM = Select[indies, Length[#] == ml &]];

(* repeat as needed *)
RandomChoice[indiesM]
```

Comment: This does not always give *maximal* matchings. So it solves the problem in the title of the question but not the one in the body...

Comment: @RahulNarain: Thanks for catching, edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly hack, but you can try randomizing the vertex order of the graph. Some algorithms are sensitive to this. There are no guarantees though. IGraph/M makes this easy.

```
g = PetersenGraph[]

Table[
 HighlightGraph[g, 
  FindIndependentEdgeSet@
   IGReorderVertices[RandomSample@VertexList[g], g]],
 {3}
 ]
```

[image]

---

Another thing you can do is add random weights ("noise") to the edges that deviate only slightly from 1. `FindIndependentEdgeSet` takes weights into account.

```
Table[
 HighlightGraph[PetersenGraph[], 
  FindIndependentEdgeSet@
   PetersenGraph[EdgeWeight -> {_ :> RandomReal[{.99, 1.01}]}]],
 {3}
 ]
```

[image]

---

Yet another thing you can do is find independent vertex sets of the line graph. `FindIndependentVertexSet` can list *all* of them.